# Как добавить проверку на наличия мьюта (а именно time-out) у учасника сервера?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord, disnake

Я столкнулся с проблемой, что если дать человеку timeout к примеру на 10 минут и через 2 минуты снова написать на 10 минут, то человеку снова дадут мут, хотя он уже был замьючен. Я бы хотел этого избежать и добавить команду на проверку наличия мьюта. Если человека замьютили и какой-то человек снова пишет эту команду этому же участнику то должно выводиться сообщение по типу "У учасника @username уже есть мьют!". Помогите, пожалуйста. Заранее большое спасибо!

Вот как правильно работает команда:

```
>мьют @username 10мин нарушил
```

Вот код:

```
@bot.command(aliases=["Мьют"])
async def мьют(ctx, member: disnake.Member, time=None, *, reason=None):
    if not ctx.author.guild_permissions.kick_members:
        embed = disnake.Embed(description=f'❌ У вас недостаточно прав чтобы замьютить!', color=0xc80005)
        return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    if member != None:
        if time != None:
            time=time.replace('час', 'h').replace('мин', 'm').replace('сек', 's')
            t = humanfriendly.parse_timespan(time)
            time=time.replace('h', 'час').replace('m', 'мин').replace('s', 'сек')
            await member.timeout(until = disnake.utils.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=t), reason=reason)
            if reason != None:
                embed = disnake.Embed(
                    description = f'✅ Учасник {member.mention} успешно замьючен на {time} {reason}',
                    color=0xc80005)
                await member.send(f"Модератор {ctx.author.mention} замьютил Вас на сервере **{ctx.guild.name}** на {time} по причине: {reason}.")
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                embed = disnake.Embed(
                    description = f'**✅ Учасник {member.mention}** замучен на {time}',
                    color=0xc80005)
                await member.send(f"Модератор {ctx.author.mention} замьютил Вас на сервере **{ctx.guild.name}** на {time}.")
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            embed = disnake.Embed(
                description = f'❌ {ctx.author}  укажите  время  наказания',
                color=0xc80005)        
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = disnake.Embed(
            description = f'❌ {ctx.author}  укажите  кого  нужно  наказать',
            color=0xc80005)        
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Вот как должно реагировать если 2 раза написать одно и тоже сообщение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, это невозможно. Сам искал. Но щас перерою все документации, мб найду)))

Comment: Если найдете как это исправить я очень сильно буду благодарен)

Comment: По-моему нашёл!))))

Comment: давайте делать историю уважаемый Чёткая Четырка)))

Comment: Ну как?)) Работает? @Lordeyser

Comment: Я смотрел и ниче не понял куда его вставлять как бы странно это не звучало XD можете пожалуйста вставить полный код с тем что вы добавили для disnake огромное спасибо!)

Comment: @Lordseyer добавил код в ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для [discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py) это выглядит так:

```
if member.communication_disabled_until == None:
    em121 = discord.Embed(title='Ошибка', description=f':x: У пользователя {member.mention} отсутствует мьют.', color=0xFF5733)
    await ctx.respond(embed=em121)
else:
    #мьют есть
```

Для [disnake](/questions/tagged/disnake) так (не проверял, но вроде должно работать):

```
if member.current_timeout == None:
    em121 = disnake.Embed(title='Ошибка', description=f':x: У пользователя {member.mention} отсутствует мьют.', color=0xFF5733)
    await ctx.respond(embed=em121)
else:
    #мьют есть
```

---

Итак, ваш полный код:

```
@bot.command(aliases=["Мьют"])
async def мьют(ctx, member: disnake.Member, time=None, *, reason=None):
    if not ctx.author.guild_permissions.kick_members:
        embed = disnake.Embed(description=f'❌ У вас недостаточно прав чтобы замьютить!', color=0xc80005)
        return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    if member != None:
        if time != None:

            if member.current_timeout != None:
                em121 = disnake.Embed(title='Ошибка', description=f':x: У пользователя {member.mention} уже есть таймаут.', color=0xFF5733)
                await ctx.respond(embed=em121)
            else:
                time=time.replace('час', 'h').replace('мин', 'm').replace('сек', 's')
                t = humanfriendly.parse_timespan(time)
                time=time.replace('h', 'час').replace('m', 'мин').replace('s', 'сек')
                await member.timeout(until = disnake.utils.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=t), reason=reason)
                if reason != None:
                    embed = disnake.Embed(
                        description = f'✅ Учасник {member.mention} успешно замьючен на {time} {reason}',
                        color=0xc80005)
                    await member.send(f"Модератор {ctx.author.mention} замьютил Вас на сервере **{ctx.guild.name}** на {time} по причине: {reason}.")
                    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                else:
                    embed = disnake.Embed(
                        description = f'**✅ Учасник {member.mention}** замучен на {time}',
                        color=0xc80005)
                    await member.send(f"Модератор {ctx.author.mention} замьютил Вас на сервере **{ctx.guild.name}** на {time}.")
                    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            embed = disnake.Embed(
                description = f'❌ {ctx.author}  укажите  время  наказания',
                color=0xc80005)        
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = disnake.Embed(
            description = f'❌ {ctx.author}  укажите,  кого  нужно  наказать',
            color=0xc80005)        
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: должно быть что-то по типу такого ```if role in member.roles:
        embed = disnake.Embed(description=f"❌ **{member.display_name}** уже замьючен(а).", color=0xc80005)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)``` это просто пример

Comment: ЗАЧЕМ? Проверьте мой код, работает?

Comment: `member.roles` юзается НЕ при таймаутах, а при мьюте с помощью ролей

Comment: Она не правильно работает. Мне нужно наоборот. Смотрите к примеру вы дали челику мут на час а пишу эту же команду только на 2 часа а бот должен доложить об ошибке мол этот пользователь и так имеет мут.  то есть если я напишу 2 раза команду ```>мьют @username 10мин нарушил``` то бот выдаст человеку мут и если 2 раз напишу ```>мьют @username 10мин нарушил``` то бот уже должен ответить вы уже замьютили. Я добавлю фотографии сверху как должно работать

Comment: кароче я нашел вот как нужно измените свой ответ и я поставлю принят чтобы другие поняли как сделать проверку. Огромное спасибо! вот код: ```if member.current_timeout is not None:
                embed = disnake.Embed(description=f'❌ Учасник {member.mention} уже имеет мьют.', color=0xc80005)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)```

Comment: Исправил @Lordeyser. Если помог, поставьте галочку и проголосуйте=)

Comment: Огромное спасибо Чёткая Четырка) как всегда выручаете)

Comment: @Lordeyser :) да не за что